# Can I do case insensitive search with JSON_EXTRACT in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, json

I am running `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title")) = 'hello world'` with the intent that `hello world` is data from a user that I will flatten to all lowercase. The actual value in my db is "Hello World", but this search comes back empty every time.

If I do a `SELECT LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title")) FROM mytable`, it certainly comes back lowercase as `hello world`. Not sure what I'm missing here.

**Queries to get actual values:**

`SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title")  FROM mytable` gets me `"Hello World"`

`SELECT LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title"))  FROM mytable` gets me `"hello world"`

**Queries trying to find the right row**

*Gets me value*

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title") = "Hello World"`

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE metadata->"$.title" = "Hello World"`

`SELECT * FROM ututs WHERE LOWER(metadata->"$.title")  LIKE "%hello world%"`

*Gets me nothing*

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title") = "hello world"`

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title") LIKE  "%hello world%"`

`SELECT * FROM ututs WHERE LOWER(metadata->"$.title") = "hello world"`

`SELECT * FROM ututs WHERE LOWER(metadata->"$.title")  LIKE "hello"`

So it looks like the result is giving back the value, including quotes. That doesn't appear to be the issue though, given I get a result when I match the case. I am also confused why the `%` at the start is solving my issue. There is no space between the `"` and `H`. I typed the JSON out myself.

I also updated `metadata` column straight to `{"title":"Hello World"}` by manually typing. MySQL automatically adds a space after colon to make it `{"title": "Hello World"}`, which is fine, but was just sanity checking any spaces.

Comment: Copy and paste the `hello world` result of the 2nd query into the where clause of the 1st, and use a fuzzy like instead of `=`.  Maybe your whitespace character is not the same?

Comment: Are you sure that `SELECT LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title")) FROM mytable` only returns `hello world`, and no other characters? If `hello world` is only part of the returned value, then you may want to use `LIKE '%hello world%'`. Post your exact JSON string in your question so we can help you better.

Comment: Try [JSON_UNQUOTE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote) or [->>](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path).

Comment: Updated question per your comments!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title")) = JSON_QUOTE("hello world")` and `SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE LOWER(metadata->"$.title") = JSON_QUOTE("hello world")` works, but I'm not sure why I need to use `JSON_QUOTE` when using `LOWER` vs not needing it for an exact search.

If someone can explain why, I will gladly mark them as the answer.

Comment: For MySQL JSON_QUOTED_STRING = "SIMPLE STRING", but LOWER(JSON_QUOTED_STRING) != LOWER("SIMPLE STRING")
So you can lower(json_unquote(JSON)) = "value" or lower(JSON) = JSON_QOUTE("value")

Comment: It's because the JSON_EXTRACT returns the value in double-quotes ("hello world") while the value OP providing for comparison was not in quotes (hell world)

Answer (score 14):

I ran into a similar case-sensitivity issue using a `like`.
I solved it by casting the output from the JSON function as a `CHAR`.

[This article](https://database.guide/json_unquote-remove-quotes-from-a-json-document-in-mysql/) mentioned that JSON functions return a `utf8mb4 string`. This leads me to believe that a different data type is being returned (maybe a byte array) instead of a `VARCHAR`. Which would explain why case-insensitive text searching was failing.

```
select
json_unquote(json_extract(json, '$.reservation.status')) as status,
json_unquote(json_extract(json, '$.reservation.status')) like '%cancelled%' as case_sensitive,
cast(json_unquote(json_extract(json, '$.reservation.status')) as CHAR) like '%cancelled%' as case_insensitive
from myTable
```

The output from this query is:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|        status       |  case_sensitive  |  case_insensitive   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      Cancelled      |        0         |         1           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|        New          |        0         |         0           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [column->>path](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_json-inline-path) to get data:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(metadata, "$.title")) LIKE  "%hello world%"

OR

SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE metadata->>"$.title" LIKE  "%hello world%"
```

To make it case insensitive

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE LOWER(metadata->>"$.title") = "hello world"
```

Comment: ->> does not resolve the case sensitivity issue: "MySQL handles strings used in JSON context using the utf8mb4 character set and utf8mb4_bin collation."

Comment: @mstrthealias Thanks for the quote! Can you link to where it came from?

Comment: @mstrthealias That's why I used LOWER()