# Laravel Eloquent case insensitive with JSON fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a json field in mysql which holds the products' names, with a different locale for each name, for example, product #1, its' 'name' column holds this -

```
{
    "en": "JBL Headphones",
    "de": "JBL Kopfhörer",
    "ru": "наушники JBL"
}
```

Now, I have route in my web.php that reacts to the product's name (/proudct/{product_name}) and should retrieve the right result, but i'm kinda struggling to make it totally case insensitive.

What I also tried with no success is -

#1

```
$asset_locale_name = 'name->'.$this->subdomain; //results in 'name->en', for example
$product = Products::where('LOWER('.$product_locale_name.')', 'LIKE', '%'.strtolower($procut_name).'%')->first();
```

#2

```
$asset_locale_name = 'name->'.$this->subdomain; //results in 'name->en', for example
$product = Product::whereRaw("UPPER('{$asset_local_name}') LIKE '%'". strtoupper($value)."'%'");
```

Comment: is `$asset_locale_name` gives its value and do `toSql()` to see the final query

Comment: have you tried to cast it as CHAR https://stackoverflow.com/a/59000485/4369919

Comment: @Pradeep - it works perfectly when I don't handle the case sensitivity issue, like this -   `$name = 'name->'.$this->subdomain;
        $product = Products::where($name, $product_name)->first();`

Comment: try with this `Product::whereRaw("UPPER('{$asset_local_name}') LIKE '%". strtoupper($value)."%'")` and make sure `asset_local_name` has proper column name

Comment: @Pradeep - $asset_locale_name has "name->en", which is a proper column name (when it comes to JSON columns) and the query you sent returns 'null', even though it's not supposed to..

Comment: when I toSql() this query of yours, I'm getting - `"select * from \`Products\` where UPPER('name->en') LIKE '%jBL hEADphones%'"`

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution is matching with JSON_EXTRACT to support insensitive cases, you can easily target specific node of your Json field and cast it as you want. here is an example:

```
$column = 'name';
$node = '$.'. $this->subdomain; // result : $.en 
$product = Product::whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(LOWER({$column}), '{$node}') = '". strtolower($procut_name)."'")->first();
```

**BUT** This is **NOT** secure because it's susceptible to SQL injections. You should use parameter binding like this:

```
$product = Product::whereRaw("JSON_EXTRACT(LOWER({$column}), '{$node}') = ?", ["'". strtolower($procut_name)."'"])->first();
```

Comment: It looks promising but it doesn't work. I get 'null' as a result. For now, the only quick n' dirty approach that worked for me is - `Product::whereRaw('LOWER(name->"$.en") like ?', '%'.strtolower('HeadphOnes').'%'))->first();`